# revoke ipad access to my wireless network

Tags: ipad, network, wifi

My elderly neighbor needed help with iPad.  So as I was helping her with it, I gave her access to my wireless network to ensure it was working properly.  Now, she "accidentally" prints to my printer often because she does not choose her own printer.  I know I could "forget device" from ipad but I am not physically with her right now.  Is there anyway that I can remove her ipad access, by removing it from my Mac?  Where do I find the list of those devices that have access to my wireless network?
Thanks!

Comment: What type of wireless router do you have?  Any information about your network setup (without revealing personal information, of course) would help us in determining an answer.

Comment: We have an Airport Extreme and use old router as a booster.

Comment: How about changing your network password?

Comment: If she already has access would changing the password kick her (and all other devices) off until new password was entered?

Comment: Yes, it should.  You would have to reenter the new password in your own devices.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution would be to change the network password.  This can be done from the **Airport Utility** application found in your Applications > Utilities folder.

This will disconnect all devices, so it would require entering the new password in your devices including your connected printer.

Airport Utility also will show you devices connected to your network.  See also [Apple Support](https://www.apple.com/support/airport/) for Airport.